# Using egg_mode to connect to twitter stream returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: twitter, rust, rust-cargo, mode, egg

I'm trying to use the egg_mode crate to retrieve a stream of tweets as per the example [here](https://github.com/egg-mode-rs/egg-mode/blob/master/examples/stream_filter.rs) but with just a slight difference in the way I input my token.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let con_token = egg_mode::KeyPair::new(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    println!("Live streaming tweets...");

    println!("Ctrl-C to quit\n");

    let stream = egg_mode::stream::filter()
        .track(&["rustlang"])
        .start(&Token::Bearer(BEARERTOKEN.to_string()))
        .try_for_each(|m| {
            if let StreamMessage::Tweet(tweet) = m {
                println!("{}\n{}",tweet.created_at,tweet.text);
           } else {
                println!("{:?}",m);
            }
            futures::future::ok(())
        });
    if let Err(e) = stream.await {
        println!("Stream error: {}", e);
        println!("Disconnected")
    }
}
```

However I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error.

Using the same bearer token, I am able to retrieve tweets with no problem using egg_mode::tweet::user_timeline as per the example [here](https://github.com/egg-mode-rs/egg-mode/blob/master/examples/bearer.rs).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It has succeeded after passing the Access variant of the Token enum instead of the Bearer variant.